# Excel VBA: Run macro without selecting cell

Tags: excel, vba

I am writing a VBA macro that imports some text from a text file and then I am splitting the text based on the delimiter ^. I have managed to get this working but am only able to run the macro if is does from the 'Import Data' sheet, otherwise I get a 1004 error.

I have debugged the issue and know the problem is with

> Worksheets("Import Data").Range("A" & rownumber).Select

After some googling I have determined that I can't select a cell in another worksheet. But I am not sure how to avoid this. How can I run the below code without selecting the cell beforehand. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

```
Worksheets("Import Data").Range("A" & rownumber).Select

    
    Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=Worksheets("Import Data").Range("c" & rownumber), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
        TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=False, _
        Semicolon:=False, Comma:=False, Space:=False, Other:=True, OtherChar _
        :="^", FieldInfo:=Array(Array(1, 1), Array(2, 1), Array(3, 1), Array(4, 1), Array(5, _
        1), Array(6, 1), Array(7, 1), Array(8, 1), Array(9, 1), Array(10, 1), Array(11, 1), Array(12 _
        , 1), Array(13, 1), Array(14, 1), Array(15, 1), Array(16, 1), Array(17, 1), Array(18, 1), _
        Array(19, 1), Array(20, 1), Array(21, 1), Array(22, 1), Array(23, 1), Array(24, 1), Array( _
        25, 1), Array(26, 1), Array(27, 1), Array(28, 1), Array(29, 1), Array(30, 1), Array(31, 1), _
        Array(32, 1), Array(33, 1), Array(34, 1), Array(35, 1)), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
```

Comment: Remove `Worksheets("Import Data").Range("A" & rownumber).Select` and replace `Selection` with `Worksheets("Import Data").Range("A" & rownumber)`.

Answer (score 0):

The `<something>.Select, Selection.<do_something>` part is a result of recording a macro.

If you want to launch this piece of code in your current (`Active`) worksheet, you can change your code into:

```
ActiveSheet.Range("A" & rownumber).TextToColumns ...
```